# Identifing guests sprouting in potted plants

Tags: identification

I have several plants (peppers, dwarf fruit trees & various herbs mostly) that I keep outside except for when temperatures are too low & I move then indoors under grow lights.

After several weeks of having my plants indoors, I noticed a couple of guests sprouting in the margins of a couple of the pots. Normally I would just pluck any invaders I find, but both of these are somewhat nice looking plants & depending on what they are, I may consider transplanting them elsewhere. Any ideas?

The leaves of the green one are about 1 1/2" long, & the leaves of the red tinged one are about 1" long.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I live in the San Francisco bay area, so if they were contaminated outside, that is relevant, although it is also possible I suppose that they were in the potting soil the whole time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alas, @Escoce, I pulled these today & I feel I can say with a fair level of certainty, that they are not in fact Holly plants, but in fact Oak. +1 because the one especially does look like Holly, but I think the acorns attached below the soil surface are a dead give away.

That said, I can't explain how in the world they got into my potting soil, or why they appear so radically different in colouring, perhaps a non-favorable soil? Wonder if I should replant them somewhere...

[image]

Comment: You know I was goi g to challenge this, wondering how that could be, but I did a little google research and discovered there is indeed a Quercus Ilex (Holly Oak), which is an oak that looks like a holly.

Answer (score 2):

Those plants are some form or another of holly. Birds probably dropped them in their when they pooped a seed.

Comment: Thanks! The greener one especially looks a bit like English Holly. These will now be getting plucked along with the other weeds.